# image feature detection with large structuring element

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, python-3.x, scipy

I am trying to extract some features from an image but each of the extracted features are really small. The easiest way to extract larger features seems to be to use a larger structuring element but the following code fails when `ITER > 1`.

```
from scipy import ndimage,misc
lena=misc.lena().astype(float64)
lena/=ndimage.maximum(lena)
lena=lena>0.54# convert to binary image
       #   =====================  
ITER=1 # || FAILS WHEN ITER > 1 ||
       #   =====================
struct=ndimage.generate_binary_structure(2,1)
struct=ndimage.iterate_structure(struct,ITER)
lena_label,n =ndimage.label(lena,struct)
slices=ndimage.find_objects(lena_label)
images=[lena[sl] for sl in slices]
imshow(images[0])
```

.

```
RuntimeError: structure dimensions must be equal to 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter `structure` for the `ndimage.label` function is used to determine the connectivity of the input. When you represent the input as a rectangular matrix, this connectivity commonly regards either the 4 or the 8 neighbors around a point `p`. Scipy follows this convention and limits the accepted structure to such cases, therefore it raises an error when anything larger than `3x3` is passed to the function.

If you really want to do such thing, first you need to define very clearly the connectivity you are trying to describe. Then you need to implement it. A simpler way is to first dilate the input, and then label it. This will effectively give the larger features that would be labeled with a larger `structure` parameter.

Comment: I want to use a connectivity similar to the structure generated by `ndimage.iterate_structure(struct,2)`. That way, if two features are separated by one pixel, they are considered to be the same feature. Does dilation have the exact same effect as using a larger structure?

Comment: If you dilate with an elementary square, these two features separated by one pixel will be joined. Thus they will be labeled as a single feature.